# Loop over only 5 items out of 10 elements present in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an 10 objects inside an array as below:

```
let arr = [{"id":1, "name": "abc"},{"id":2, "name": "fsd"},{"id":3, "name": "fasd"},{"id":4, "name": "fsdfas"},{"id":5, "name": "fad"},{"id":6, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":7, "name": "fasd"},{"id":8, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":9, "name": "fasdfs"},{"id":10, "name": "abc"}]
```

My query: I want to loop over only first 5 objects within the array and break the loop. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with writing a loop that does this? Please show us your attempt.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

It looks like you are using ES2015+, so take note of `let i` in the for loop constraints. This avoids the value of the `i` variable leaking into outer scope.

Answer (score 2):

Old school:

```js
let arr = [{"id":1, "name": "abc"},{"id":2, "name": "fsd"},{"id":3, "name": "fasd"},{"id":4, "name": "fsdfas"},{"id":5, "name": "fad"},{"id":6, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":7, "name": "fasd"},{"id":8, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":9, "name": "fasdfs"},{"id":10, "name": "abc"}]

// Math.min (just in case arr.length < 5)
for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(5, arr.length); i++) { 
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Better: `i<Math.min(5, arr.length)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
let arr = [{"id":1, "name": "abc"},{"id":2, "name": "fsd"},{"id":3, "name": "fasd"},{"id":4, "name": "fsdfas"},{"id":5, "name": "fad"},{"id":6, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":7, "name": "fasd"},{"id":8, "name": "fasdf"},{"id":9, "name": "fasdfs"},{"id":10, "name": "abc"}]

arr.slice(0, 5).forEach( item => console.log(item));
```